# linux server ca-bundle.crt

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have stage server which I use it with Putty. I enter into another 4 linux servers via stage server. The four servers are 192.168.0.11, 192.168.0.12, 192.168.0.13, 192.168.0.14

On the 192.168.0.12 linux server at this path /usr/share/ssl/certs there is a file named "ca-bundle.crt" (file size 249373 bytes). Somehow, by mistake I did "vi ca-bundle.crt" and it got cleaned and now the size is 0 byte.

All the four servers have this file and with same size (249373 bytes).

So, I brought the ca-bundle.crt from another server(say 192.168.0.11) and paste at the same location of 192.168.0.12/usr/share/ssl/certs

So, will it create any problem? Is the ca-bundle.crt server specific?

Comment: it shouldn't be difficult to test, all you have to do is HTTPS to this server and check that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ca-bundle.crt is the bundle of certificates that the server trusts.  Usually this is installed by default by the distribution.  I'm going to assume that all servers are for the same distribution.

Of course, certificates can be added to this file; for example if you use self-signed certificates a lot in your organization.

It sounds like the file was still the default on all the machines (or at least they were the same.  I would confirm it with md5sum on the 3 other servers just to compare).

It's unlikely you'll have any problems.  It would make sense to have those servers managed such that when someone overwites a file in deployment, that file can be recovered - either from backups, configuration management systems (like Puppet), or the default package.